# UI is not updating on click event that triggers a fetch on Firefox Developer

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I built a project of Frontend Mentors called Advice generator App using HTML, CSS & JS. There is a bug with my solution and Firefox Developer. When I clicked on the button, the event listener run the fetch function and makes a request and changes the UI accordingly to the data received from the response; the problem is that when I click again, the UI doesn't change and the console shows the same response as before; this didn't happen on brave browser and I suppose other Chromium-based browsers as well, I want to know why this happens with Firefox Developer?

- Link of repo: https://github.com/Perlishnov/advice-generator-app-main
- Link of website: https://advice-generator-app-main-kappa.vercel.app/

```js
"use strict";

//Html Elements
const rollDice = document.getElementById("roll-dice");
const adviceNumber = document.getElementById("advice-number");
const adviceParagraph = document.getElementById("advice");
const url = "https://api.adviceslip.com/advice";

//Dice button logic
rollDice.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(
      (data) => (
        (adviceNumber.textContent = data.slip.id),
        (adviceParagraph.textContent = data.slip.advice)
      )
    );
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's looks like a cache memory issue. if the url is the same, the browser uses what is already in the cache.

The simplest way to fix that: add a counter on your url, to force the cache

```js
"use strict";

//Html Elements
const
  rollDice        = document.getElementById('roll-dice')
, adviceNumber    = document.getElementById('advice-number')
, adviceParagraph = document.getElementById('advice')
, url = 
   { ref   : 'https://api.adviceslip.com/advice'
   , count : 0
   }
 ;

//Dice button logic
rollDice.onclick = () => 
  {
  fetch( `${url.ref}?c=${++url.count}`)
  .then( r => r.json() )
  .then( data =>
    {
    adviceNumber.textContent    = data.slip.id
    adviceParagraph.textContent = data.slip.advice
    })
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 id="advice-number"> n </h3>
  <p  id="advice">...</p>
</div>
<button id="roll-dice"> roll-dice </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I discover while reading in the Frontend Mentor website that this happens because Firefox cache the response from the API. So the only you have to do is pass an object with the property of `cache` and then set it to `no cache`  as the second argument of the fetch API. like this

```
  "use strict";

//Html Elements
const rollDice = document.getElementById("roll-dice");
const adviceNumber = document.getElementById("advice-number");
const adviceParagraph = document.getElementById("advice");
const url = "https://api.adviceslip.com/advice";

//Dice button logic
rollDice.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch(url, {cache: "no-cache"})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(
      (data) => (
        (adviceNumber.textContent = data.slip.id),
        (adviceParagraph.textContent = data.slip.advice)
      )
    );
});
```